# How to auto adjust "backgroundImage" based on the screen size width "mobile and desktop view" in react js material ui

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJS and I'm able to developing the design pages but my query is my designed pages is not properly adjust based on the screen size width(desktop and mobile view) below is my logic

Import files:-

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardContent, Paper, CardMedia, IconButton, Typography, Container, Grid, Box, styled, Button } from "@mui/material";
import Maerocket from './../../img/rocket.png';
import Maedotted_vertical from './../../img/dotted_vertical.png';
```

Function logic:-

```
function HomePage() {
return (

<Container maxWidth="lg">
<Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ pt: "68px" }}>
<Grid item xs={12} md={4}>

<Card sx={{ bgcolor: "#C6EFEF", borderRadius: "10px", backgroundImage: `url(${Maerocket})`, backgroundSize: "250px", backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
backgroundPosition: "right center", backgroundPositionX: "150px", position: "relative",
                          '&::after': {
position: "absolute", content: '""', backgroundImage: `url(${Maedotted_vertical})`, backgroundSize: "17px 30px", backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat", backgroundPosition: "bottom left", display: "block", bottom: 25, left: 10, width: '50px', height: '100px',
},
}}>

                       
<CardContent>
<Typography sx={{ color: "#012B4E", fontSize: "25px", pt: "27px", pb: "28px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Algo Trading</Typography>
<Typography sx={{ color: "#012B4E", fontSize: "16px", pb: "10px", fontWeight: 600 }}>Simplified!</Typography>
<Typography sx={{ color: "#012B4E", fontSize: "14px", fontWeight: 600 }}>Start your Algo Trading journey</Typography>
<Typography sx={{ color: "#012B4E", fontSize: "14px", pb: "38px", fontWeight: 600 }}>with Modern Algos</Typography>
</CardContent>
 </Card>

</Grid>
</Grid>
</Container>

 );
}
```

Desktop view look like this:-

[image: Desktop view]

And in mobile view look like this:-

[image: Mobile view]

Please suggest me why in the mobile view (based on the width) the backgroundImage is not coming properly.
Where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You can use the in built `useMediaquery` from MUI https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/

Comment: did you try `object-fit: contain;` css for background img?